# Custom View for drawing not showing up

Tags: android

I want to create a custom view that will contain 2D drawings (circle, square, lines, and so forth).

I've implemented the onCreate method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinePlotter lp = new LinePlotter(this, 500, 500);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500,500));
    layout.addView(lp);

    LinearLayout main = findViewById(R.id.linearTest);
    main.addView(layout);

}
```

And my LinePlotter class like this:

```
package com.inti.plottest;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.View;

public class LinePlotter extends View {

    private int WIDTH;
    private int HEIGHT;

    public LinePlotter(Context context, int width, int height) {
        super(context);
        WIDTH = width;
        HEIGHT = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        System.err.println("Por aca pase");
        canvas.drawColor(5614080);
    }
}
```

For starters all I want to see is a 500x500 px square right below a button (which is part of the activity_main.xml), I'm adding it just in case the problem is there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearTest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onDoTestClicked"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Why is it not showing up?

EDIT: As suggested I've added this function to my Line Plotter class

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    System.err.println("Me midieron");
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
}
```

However it still does not show up.

Comment: Try setting the `LayoutParams` on your `LinePlotter` view, not the parent view.

Comment: @aarelovich check my edit pls, you have wrong color in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your View does not have any size, try check it in LayoutInspector. 
You must override `onMeasure` method and measure view's size by calling

`setMeasuredDimension(width, height)`

Here is a good article with details
https://medium.com/@quiro91/custom-view-mastering-onmeasure-a0a0bb11784d

EDIT: Also change Color to correct one, canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE) for example